# How to parse json from wp-scan?

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
{
"crius":{
"latest_version":null,"last_updated":null,"popular":false,"vulnerabilities":
    [{
    "id":7306,
    "title":"Crius - VideoJS Cross-Site Scripting Vulnerability",
    "created_at":"2014-08-01T10:59:16.000Z",
    "updated_at":"2015-05-15T13:48:44.000Z",
    "published_date":null,
    "references":{"url":["http://seclists.org/fulldisclosure/2013/May/77"],"secunia":["53427"]},"vuln_type":"XSS","fixed_in":null}]}
}
```

How to parse them with python 2.7? Thanks.

Comment: you can use the `json` module: https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

Comment: i want to get values: latest_version,last_updated,popular, vulnerabilities ->id,....

Answer (score 0):

Use [`json.loads()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.loads):

```
import json

s = '''{
"crius":{
"latest_version":null,"last_updated":null,"popular":false,"vulnerabilities":
    [{
    "id":7306,
    "title":"Crius - VideoJS Cross-Site Scripting Vulnerability",
    "created_at":"2014-08-01T10:59:16.000Z",
    "updated_at":"2015-05-15T13:48:44.000Z",
    "published_date":null,
    "references":{"url":["http://seclists.org/fulldisclosure/2013/May/77"],"secunia":["53427"]},"vuln_type":"XSS","fixed_in":null}]}
}'''

data = json.loads(s)

>>> data
{u'crius': {u'popular': False, u'vulnerabilities': [{u'title': u'Crius - VideoJS Cross-Site Scripting Vulnerability', u'created_at': u'2014-08-01T10:59:16.000Z', u'updated_at': u'2015-05-15T13:48:44.000Z', u'vuln_type': u'XSS', u'references': {u'url': [u'http://seclists.org/fulldisclosure/2013/May/77'], u'secunia': [u'53427']}, u'published_date': None, u'fixed_in': None, u'id': 7306}], u'last_updated': None, u'latest_version': None}}
```

Comment: print data["latest_version"]
KeyError: 'latest_version' ???

Comment: @LyĐào .. Do you think simply `data["latest_version"]` will simply give you the corresponding value???..com'n...It's a nested dictionary !!!

Comment: look at your data structure: to access "latest_version", you need to use `data["crius"]["latest_version"]`